# ValueError - Cannot assign "u''"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to edit some code of another developer. All went well, until i got this error:

> ValueError at /berichten/registreren/
>   Cannot assign "u''": "Bericht.beller" must be a "Beller" instance.

I'll start with the traceback:

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/berichten/registreren/

Django Version: 1.4.3
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',


'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'mm')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'mm.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  172.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  137.         if form.is_valid():
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  124.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  115.             self.full_clean()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  272.         self._post_clean()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  309.         self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in construct_instance
  51.             f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in save_form_data
  454.         setattr(instance, self.name, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __set__
  366.                                  self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /berichten/registreren/
Exception Value: Cannot assign "u''": "Bericht.beller" must be a "Beller" instance.
```

**Models.py**

```
class Beller(models.Model):
    titel = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    naam = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    voornaam = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bedrijf = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    adres = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    plaats = models.ForeignKey(Plaats, blank=True, null=True)
    telefoon = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    taal = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TAAL)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['naam', 'voornaam']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{0} {1}".format(self.naam, self.voornaam)

class Bericht(models.Model):
    klant = models.ForeignKey(Klant)
    lijn = models.ForeignKey(Lijn)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    beller = models.ForeignKey(Beller)

    tijdstip = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    bericht = models.TextField(blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BERICHT_STATUS)
    gebruiker = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

**forms.py**

```
class BerichtForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lijn = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Lijn.objects.filter(datum_tot__exact=None))
    contact_naam = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    contact_pk = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    beller = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    titel = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=10)
    naam = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    voornaam = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50)
    bedrijf = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50)
    adres = forms.CharField(required=False)
    plaats_pk = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    plaats = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    telefoon = forms.CharField(required=False)
    taal = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=TAAL))

    class Meta:
        model = Bericht
        fields = ('lijn', 'contact_naam', 'beller', 'naam', 'titel', 'voornaam', 'bedrijf', 'adres', 'plaats', 'email', 'telefoon', 'taal', 'bericht',)
```

**views.py**

```
class BerichtCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Bericht
    template_name = "mm/bericht/form.html"
    form_class = BerichtForm
    context_object_name = "bericht"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('mm-berichten-registreren')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BerichtCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cb = self.request.GET.get('cb', None)
        if cb:
            context['cb'] = cb
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.cb:
            return self.success_url + "?cb=" + self.cb
        else:
            return self.success_url

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Valideer het formulier, maar voeg eerst de klant toe aan de instance """
        self.cb = None
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.klant = self.object.lijn.klant

        # Verwerk contact info
        contact_pk = form.cleaned_data['contact_pk']
        try:
            contact = int(contact_pk)
        except:
            contact = None
        if contact:
            self.object.contact = Contact.objects.get(pk=contact)
        else:
            self.object.contact = Contact()

        # Verwerk beller info
        beller = form.cleaned_data['beller']
        if beller:
            try:
                beller = Beller.objects.get(pk=beller)
            except Beller.DoesNotExist:
                beller = Beller()
        else:
            beller = Beller()

        beller.titel = form.cleaned_data['titel']
        beller.naam = form.cleaned_data['naam']
        beller.voornaam = form.cleaned_data['voornaam']
        beller.bedrijf = form.cleaned_data['bedrijf']
        beller.adres = form.cleaned_data['adres']
        if form.cleaned_data['plaats_pk']:
            beller.plaats = Plaats.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['plaats_pk'])
        else:
            beller.plaats = None
        beller.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        beller.telefoon = form.cleaned_data['telefoon']
        beller.taal = form.cleaned_data['taal']
        beller.save()
        #self.object.beller = beller
        self.object.gebruiker = self.request.user
        self.object.save()

        if self.request.POST.get('versturen', None):
            self.cb = None

            # Verwerk e-mail communicatie
            if self.object.contact.contact_medium == 'E':
                self.object.send_email()

                if self.object.status == "N":
                    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.WARNING, 'Het bericht kon niet via e-mail worden verstuurd.')
                else:
                    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Het bericht is verstuurd naar de contactpersoon.')

            else:
                # Add a callback for print to success url
                self.cb = reverse('mm-bericht-afdrukken', args=[self.object.id])
                self.object.status = 'P'

        else:
            self.object.status = 'D'
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Het bericht is opgeslagen maar is nog niet verstuurd.')

        self.object.save()

        return super(BerichtCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

As you see, i'm trying to send a Beller() instance, yet it doesn't.

Already thanking you for trying to help me out.

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited with picture from complete page. Hope it helps

Comment: your screenshot is not readable. Other thing is you shouldn't be copying the settings details with credential etc. On which action you are running into this issue. It seems like string assignment happening instead of instance of your Beller class

Comment: @Mutant: Well, to be fair, if you displayed the image at normal size (which in Firefox for Windows is right-click, "View Image", then click on the image if you see the magnifying glass with a plus on it), you *could* read it. It's moot now, as he's removed the image.

Comment: try inserting import pdb;pdb.set_trace() above your beller Assignment and try to debug the error. If you are not aware about debugging in python, check details here - http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring during validation, not in your `form_valid()` method. It's trying to validate a string to the "`beller`" field on a `Bericht` object. Django is doing this because it's told that is one of the fields that should be automatically saved with the model.

In fields in the meta of `BerichtForm`, only include fields that exist on the `Bericht` that you want to populate with data you get from the HTML directly. Something like:

```
class Meta:
    model = Bericht
    fields = ('lijn', 'tijdstip', 'bericht')
```

PS: One more piece of information that could have helped here is the content of the POST body for the request.